# Использование функции prepare() для requests python

Tags: python, python-3.x, запрос, requests

Составляются запросы к API и не всегда понятно изначально, что будет содержать запрос. Т.е. различные `headers`, `body` и параметры для `get`-запроса, который помещяется в конец `URL`. Перед отправкой самого запроса очень удобно пользоваться `prepare()`-функцией:

```py
def __get(self):
    req = Request("get", self.url)
    prepped = req.prepare()
    prepped.headers = self.headers
    if (self.id_obligatory and hasattr(self, "id")) or (not self.id_obligatory and hasattr(self, "id")):
        self.url += f"{self.id}/"
        prepped.url = self.url
    s = Session()
    response = s.send(prepped)
    return response
```

все замечательно работает.

Но если необходимо добавить параметры как здесь:

```py
>>> r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
```

то в этом случае такая конструкция не сработает:

```py
....
    elif hasattr(self, "oData") and self.oData_possible:
        prepped.params = self.oData # здесь не забирает данные, исключения и ошибки нет, содержание проверено и оно верно 
    s = Session()
    response = s.send(prepped)
    return response
```

На выходе я имею URL без параметров.

Есть, ли, лаконичный способ установить параметры в URL через `prepare()`? Или конкатенировать строку?

Comment: Может, всё же prepare нужно выполнять после установки params?

Comment: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#lower-level-classes

Comment: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Request.prepare

Comment: Если по русски, то prepare() собирает объект запроса и возвращает его. Вы собираете объект без параметров.

Comment: req = Request("get", self.url, params=payload)  - вот так надо бы...

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич только значение `params` не обязательно изначально. Т.е. в каждой ветке if надо создавать req и его собирать. Общее для всех запросов это `headers`  в данном примере. Все остальное опционально

Comment: Сделайте в методе класса дефолтное значение def __get(self, payload=None)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич А вот это хорошо)

Comment: там меня Pycharm как то поправлял по поводу данной конструкции ссылаясь на некий PEP. Какой не вспомню, и чего он предлагал - тоже :)